# How to align this nav bar from left to right of the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on this website and I added this nav bar to the left side of the browser. I need help with changing the side of the navbar so rather than opening from the left it should open from the right side of the browser.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.rightalign {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .3s;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span class="rightalign" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `right: 0` instead of `left: 0` on the `.sidenav`, and transition the `margin-right` instead of the `margin-left` on `#main`.

To left-justify the close button, change `right: 25px` to `left: 0` and `margin-left: 50px` to `margin-right: 50px`.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.rightalign {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-right .3s;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span class="rightalign" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: the nav bar opens from the left but the &times icon is still on the right

Comment: @F_J is that better?

Comment: &#9776; sorry I meant this sign. have to right align this